# How do I take down fast driving cars in GTA 4?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

There are some fast driving cars I need to take down in GTA 4. For instance the first mission after

> Niko found out that Michelle is an undercover cop and took him to an office,

and a most wanted list from the police computer.

The problem is those cars drive and turn so fast that I can barely keep up with them, let alone take them down. Shooting from the car doesn't help much either.

Any advice?

Comment: Hey, you know, spoiler tags excist for a reason. Just sayin.

Comment: @Moe No problem. For future reference, the spoiler markup is `>!` in front of text, so like the quote syntax except with a ! in it.

Answer (score 5):

I would say get a faster car so you can keep up with them, because the NPCs will at certain times fail and get hit by another car or drive against a wall so you can just kill the driver. Or blow it up for that matter...

Or

What I mostly do is get a SMG with loads of bullets, and in the chase I aim at their back tires, a little below or a little up since the SMG just spams around a bit. If you hit one of them and it gets a flat, then they will spin out of control most of the time. If not, shoot the other one as well...